# Ubuntu 18.10 not locking before sleep

Tags: suspend, hibernate, 18.10

I have my lid-switch `sleep-then-hibernate` with logind, but upon waking the system is still logged in, but in a seemingly unusable state with nothing but the top bar clickable and even that is graphically bugged.

If I lock the screen first then everything is good.

My question is how I can force the screen to lock before it sleeps?

Answer (score 0):

What is your lock screen setting and sleep mode setting? i think there should be a difference.

For example if setting is as below:

> Lock screen after blank for : Screen turns off
>
> Blank Screen : 5 Min

In this case Your be blank after 5 min and once the screen will blank your system will be locked. You can make setting from these settings.